# ¿Cuál es el origen de la palabra "antemano"?

Tags: etimología, historia

El significado de "de antemano" es claro: da la idea de "anticipación". Algunos ejemplos:

> No sabemos de antemano qué dirección va a tomar o cuáles puedan ser los resultados.
>
> Por lo tanto, quiero disculparme de antemano por no poder quedarme hasta el final del debate.
>
> Quiero dar las gracias de antemano a los miembros por su participación activa y decidida en esa reunión.

En el DLE se puede encontrar su explicación:

> [**antemano**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=2n59e5d)
>
> De *ante*- y *mano*.
>
> de antemano
>
> 1. loc. adv. Con anticipación, anteriormente.

Según el diccionario, la palabra está compuesta por ante y mano. "Ante" se entiende. Lo que no me queda claro es que papel juega la palabra "mano" en el significado de la palabra. ¿Es algo anatómico o qué explicación existe? Las entradas para [mano](http://dle.rae.es/?id=OF9CzGo%7COFAJXYy)  tampoco me dan alguna idea al respecto.

Comment: Démonos cuenta de que es exactametne igual en inglés: "_beforehand_". En [este hilo](https://www.reddit.com/r/etymology/comments/2x18sn/why_is_there_a_hand_at_the_end_of_beforehand/) se especula: "perhaps from the idea of one working before the hand of another, and so in anticipation of his action", es decir, algo así como que tu mano actúe antes que la del otro. Otros enlaces sugieren "of uncertain signification, unless the original notion is payment in advance." En francés es también igual: _avant main_. Parece ser que el sentido es: mi mano (mi acción) va antes que la otra cosa".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En este caso, *mano* no tiene ninguna acepción extraña: se refiere a la mano tal cual. El truco está en *ante*, que se debe entender como *[frente a](http://dle.rae.es/?id=2lpQu7Z)*. Es decir: lo que tienes frente a las manos.

Fíjate en la definición que da Covarrubias de la palabra:

> ANTEMANO, lo que se ha de presente, antes de tratar el negocio, o venta.

Es decir, la idea es: antes de tratar otras cosas, tratemos lo que tenemos delante (de las manos). Esto se ve también en las traducciones que se dan a otros idiomas en diccionarios de la misma época (principios del siglo XVII):

> Antemáno. G. devant main. I. *inanzi mano.* L prae manibus. A. *before hand.*

Fíjate que se mantiene la idea de algo "ante la mano" en todas las traducciones, incluso en latín. Los primeros casos del CORDE son del siglo XVI:

> *... y, ansí mesmo, da al tercero 12 ducados de antemano...* (1512)

Usa, como ves, el mismo significado que tiene actualmente. En algunos textos se prescinde de la preposición:

> *Alhóndiga común y mayordomos d'ella pueden comprar pan antemano, y han de ser preferidos en la compra por el tanto a otros qualesquier.* (1523-1551)

El *Diccionario de autoridades* (1729) da otro significado y explicación:

> ANTEMANO. s.m. Agasájo, dádiva, regálo, que anticipadamente se dá como prenda y señal para ganar la voluntád de alguno, à fin de lograr lo que se deséa, ò pretende de él. Dícese Antemano, porque se anticipa y dá en la mano de contádo.

Nótese que en este caso la palabra actúa como sustantivo y no como adverbio. Pero es posible que esta definición sea la que originó el uso como adverbio, aunque curiosamente no encuentro en el CORDE ninguna frase de la época que coincida con este significado. El propio *Diccionario de autoridades* pone como ejemplo una frase de Quevedo:

> *Hijas lo que conviene es tengámos y tengámos, y encomendaros al contante y al antemáno.* (1635-1645)

Lo curioso es que esta definición no sobrevivió más allá del *Diccionario de autoridades*, quedando olvidada en posteriores ediciones y apareciendo tan solo la referente al adverbio (o el modismo adverbial "de antemano"). Sin embargo, ahora que lo veo, la definición de Covarrubias sí que parece que se refiera más a la definición como sustantivo, si entendemos "lo que se ha de presente" como "lo que se da de presente". Entonces la explicación del *Autoridades* sería la válida, y se entendería "dar algo de antemano" como "dar algo como regalo anticipado". Y esto además cuadraría con algunas fichas del *Fichero general* que encuentro con la palabra en femenino y plural:

> *Decem almakanas antemanas que de parte de mea matre habui...* (1077-78).

Answer (score 0):

En mi opinión, dejando de lado la etimología... Supongo que su origen es igual que palabras como "Ojalá", que convirtieron frases en palabras de uso diario. Podría originarse de, como etimología lo indica, la "Anticipación" a algo. Esta palabra pudo originarse de que antes de cerrar un trato ( dándose la mano ) ya se sabía con anticipación el resultado de dicho trato : "Antes de la mano" (Cierre de trato con la mano [manibus ante]).